# Python TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, list

I have a list of names:

```
geneNameList = ['psaA', 'psbF', 'rpl36', 'rpoC1', 'psbK', 'atpB']
```

and a list of positions:

```
positionList = ['_1stpos', '_2ndpos', '_3rdpos']
```

I am trying to add the strings in my position list to each of the names in my list of names so I would end up with a partitionList:

```
partitionList = ['psaA_1stpos', 'psaA_2ndpos', 'psaA_3rdpos', psbF_1stpos', 'psbF_2ndpos'... 'atpB_3rdpos']
```

I have this code:

```
partitionList = []
for i in geneNameList:
    for k in positionList:
        partition = geneNameList[i] + positionList[k] + ' = '
        partitionList.append(partition)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
    partition = geneNameList[i] + positionList[k] + ' = '
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: for i in range (len (geneNameList))  ,  you  must  write like  this

Comment: Your loops are generating the values in each list, not indexes into the lists

Comment: @nandha ... we can do better than that ... why produce indexes if you’re just going to immediately look the values up?

Comment: @donkopotamus i  understood , &  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over objects, not over integers.

Python works something like this:

Imagine that you have a list

[cat (an object with it properties), dog, human]

if you make:

```
for i in list:
```

you will be iterating over cat, dog, and human, but not over the index of the list.

You have to do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
```

So, now you are iterating over integers (list index) and not objects.

Answer (score 1):

- Change `geneNameList[i] + positionList[k] + ' = '` to `i + k` to add the values of each list.

  - `geneNameList[i]` implies you're trying to get a value based upon it's index in the list.
  - You are already iterating over the values, so you don't need to index the list.
  - Specifically, the `TypeError` is caused because you're indexing the list by a value instead of an integer. (e.g. `geneNameList['psaA']` instead of `geneNameList[0]`)
- This just resolves the issue with your code without changing your way of writing it.

```py
positionList = ['_1stpos', '_2ndpos', '_3rdpos']
geneNameList = ['psaA', 'psbF', 'rpl36', 'rpoC1', 'psbK', 'atpB']

partitionList = []
for i in geneNameList:
    for k in positionList:
        partition = i + k
        partitionList.append(partition)

print(partitionList)

['psaA_1stpos',
 'psaA_2ndpos',
 'psaA_3rdpos',
 'psbF_1stpos',
 'psbF_2ndpos',
 'psbF_3rdpos',
 'rpl36_1stpos',
 'rpl36_2ndpos',
 'rpl36_3rdpos',
 'rpoC1_1stpos',
 'rpoC1_2ndpos',
 'rpoC1_3rdpos',
 'psbK_1stpos',
 'psbK_2ndpos',
 'psbK_3rdpos',
 'atpB_1stpos',
 'atpB_2ndpos',
 'atpB_3rdpos']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) to create a cross product of each of the gene names and positions and then `join` them together in a list comprehension to produce your `partitionList`:

```
import itertools

geneNameList = ['psaA', 'psbF', 'rpl36', 'rpoC1', 'psbK', 'atpB']

positionList = ['_1stpos', '_2ndpos', '_3rdpos']

partitionList = [''.join(gp) for gp in itertools.product(geneNameList, positionList)]

print(partitionList)
```

Output:

```
[
 'psaA_1stpos', 'psaA_2ndpos', 'psaA_3rdpos',
 'psbF_1stpos', 'psbF_2ndpos', 'psbF_3rdpos',
 'rpl36_1stpos', 'rpl36_2ndpos', 'rpl36_3rdpos',
 'rpoC1_1stpos', 'rpoC1_2ndpos', 'rpoC1_3rdpos',
 'psbK_1stpos', 'psbK_2ndpos', 'psbK_3rdpos',
 'atpB_1stpos', 'atpB_2ndpos', 'atpB_3rdpos'
]
```

If you want the `=` on the end of each string, just change `''.join(gp)` to `''.join(gp) + ' = '` in the comprehension.